# Best way to deploy a web app to production

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

My technique for deploying an ASP.NET webapp into production is as follows:

Client:

- Select 'Release' mode and then right-click to publish.
- Go manually to the publish folder and zip contents.
- Now transfer to server by FTP.

Server:

- Unzip folder contents.
- Stop IIS.
- Deploy new folder contents for web app.
- Start IIS.

I don't stop the database or run any additional tools to promote to production. It's a small company, and this seems fine. What's wrong with this technique in your opinion?

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to ZIP.
Just publish via PUBLISH in the VS to your server.
IIS processes will be killed and be restarted anyhow.

Comment: Can you elaborate... I haven't seen this option. Tx.

Comment: Right-click on your project in VS, there's a "Publish" option.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy

Web Deployment Tool works with both IIS6 and IIS7 and enables automated copy deployment, file synchronization, and migrating of applications onto web servers.

Comment: This is definately the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Scott Hanselman did a presentation about the web deployment stuff in VS at MIX in 2010:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX10/FT14

Scott could probably do an entertaining presentation about drying paint, so it's worth a look if you have a chance.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing wrong with your approach is the manual intervention needed. I strongly encourage you to read [Continuous Delivery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912).